# Unexpected closing of all opened programs

Tags: .desktop

i use newest wersion of for desktop.
I want to ask if any of you have encountered a similar problem.
It happened to me several times when I clicked on the clock, everything froze for about half a second, the screen moved as if a new workspace was opening and all my programs closed without being asked to save active files.
I don't know what causes this. I don't load the laptop too much. I have enough ram and processing power and I don't think it's a crash.

Comment: There is no information to tell anything. Maybe graphical drivers are needed, etc.

Comment: x.org x server - nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau    for nvidia gforce 610 m

Comment: So install a recommended Nvidia driver

Comment: recommendet driver cause tearing on videos

Comment: tearing can be easily solved

Comment: how ...........

Comment: You can search the site and find an answer. Or ask a new question.

Comment: i;ve tryed many things buttearing is still here

Comment: that is wy i use this driver

Comment: What "many things did you try"? Anyway it is off-topic for this question. It is your choice to use nouveau with the issues, or install proprietary drives and fix the tearing.

Comment: first i try fixes from nvidia website

Comment: than fixes from ubuntu forums and anythink i found else,

Comment: there is option (proprietary, tested) but tearing is still here with it.

Comment: So post a new question about tearing.

Comment: Do not know if this helps, but 'additional drivers' lists 390 and 340 and nouveau as available, but says using manual install driver.  Nivida is saying using 440 driver.  I have not manually installed any driver myself.  Might have chosen 440 from list for clean install of 19.04.